# Ionic find if a child was clicked through parents click event

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, ionic3, dom-events

I have a checkbox with a label and Ionic triggers the checkbox event even when the label gets clicked.

I have dynamic HTML bound to the labels like this:

```
<ion-label [innerHTML]="htmlString"></ion-label>
```

and the htmlString can contain `<a>` elements. When a user clicks on these elements a certain ection has to happen. I am trying to do this without manually binding event handlers to the `<a>` elements:

```
checkBoxEvent(e){
     if ((e.target as HTMLElement).tagName === 'A') {
      alert('link found')
    }
  }
```

But it does not find the link. Any suggestions?

Here is a working/editable example:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-kdzcwt?file=pages%2Fhome%2Fhome.ts

EDIT: Sorry if it wasn't clear, but I only need to show the alert when the link is clicked. When other parts of the label are clicked, the alert should not show up.

Answer (score 1):

In your sample link, `e` is `undefined` because you did not pass `$event` as argument of `checkBoxEvent()` function. In **html template file**, you should replace `<ion-checkbox (click)="checkBoxEvent()" ></ion-checkbox>` with `<ion-checkbox (click)="checkBoxEvent($event)" ></ion-checkbox>`.

Also, `(e.target as HTMLElement).tagName` is not `'A'` but `'BUTTON'`. I think it is caused by implementation of `ion-checkbox`. So you should also replace `if ((e.target as HTMLElement).tagName === 'A')` with `if ((e.target as HTMLElement).tagName === 'BUTTON')` to get what you want.

---

**Update**

The below element covered your **innerHTML**, so click event was intercepted.

```
<button class="item-cover item-cover-md item-cover-default item-cover-default-md" ...> ...</button>
```

So **one way** is adding `z-index` to `ion-label` and adding eventlistener for `a` tag element. But you should add more code than the below if you want checkbox to work normal.

**.html**

```
<ion-label style="z-index:100;" #ref ></ion-label>
<ion-checkbox></ion-checkbox>
```

**.ts**

```
@ViewChild('ref') ref: ElementRef;
ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.ref.nativeElement.innerHTML = "This is a test label to test <a>link</a> click events";
    this.render.listen(this.ref.nativeElement.getElementsByTagName('a')[0],'click',()=>{alert('link found')})
}
```

The **other way** is using classic `checkbox` and `label` as **@Duannx** said. this way give you more elegant code but make you write more style codes.

Comment: You're right. But your recommendation is not correct. I think the OP should use html lable and checkbox instead of Ionic component

Comment: There are several ways to achieve what OP want. My way is just one of them. In my way, OP can access `a` element via its parent element without huge source code change. Of course, your way also works.

Comment: But I need to show the alert only when the <a> tag is pressed.

Comment: Oh then, My way is not right. I will modify the anwser.

Answer (score 0):

Use ViewChild to ref the ion-label component

```
 <ion-label #ref ></ion-label>
```

If you want to add Dyanamic Data infront of link and after link you need to use three  element like this

```
  <span #ref></span>
  <a #anchor (click)="onClick()" ></a>
  <span #las></span>
```

I am using template ref to ion-check box so that i can toggle if i click the link

```
  <ion-checkbox  #checkbox> </ion-checkbox>
```

**component.ts**

```
  onClick(){
         this.checkbox.checked=!this.checkbox.checked;
  }
  ngAfterViewInit(){
          this.ref.nativeElement.innerHTML=`This is a test label to test`;
          this.anchor.nativeElement.innerHTML=`link`;
          this.las.nativeElement.innerHTML=`click events`;
  }
```

Example :https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-tmizxm

Comment: Nice, but I need to show the alert only when the <a> element is clicked, not when other parts of the label are clicked

Comment: i have changed the answer check the answer! https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-tmizxm

Comment: Sorry, don't really understand what you mean, and the stackblitz doesn't show the desired result.

Comment: if you click the link you want to check the checkbox right i have updated the answer check if you click link it will check box autometicaly

Comment: No, I want the ALERT to show up ONLY when the link is clicked. Without attaching an event handler to the link. Through the checkbox event. And the checkbox shouldn't be checked when the link is clicked. If any other part of the label(not the link) is clicked, the ckeckbox should check though.